# What is the meaning of negative value of alternating waves?

Tags: ac, negative

What does the negative values in AC mean?

If we have a symmetrical sine wave with positive and negative amplitudes, then what is the physical significance of negative values?

If the answer is related to direction, then the current should travel forwards and backwards, then how does the current complete its path in the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

It is used to indicate a phase relationship.  A negative amplitude on an AC value indicates that it is 180 degrees out of phase with whatever convention we have picked for positive values.

To explain better, let's look at the simple circuit below.

The relationship here is:

\$v(t) = i(t) \cdot R\$

Note that to be careful, you have to use time dependent voltage and current values.
Assuming that v(t) is a negative amplitude AC sine wave, you will get something like this.

\$-A_Vsin(\omega t) = i(t) \cdot R\$

But from trigonometry, this is equivalent to this, which is just 180 degrees out of phase with the equivalent positive amplitude sine wave.

\$A_Vsin(-\omega t) = i(t) \cdot R\$

So, physically, a negative amplitude AC wave is just another way of describing a 180 degree phase shifted AC wave.

[image: Basic current image]

Note also what the sign used on the schematic actually means for AC.  In the schematic, current is marked as going clockwise.  This does *not* mean that the current is always flowing in that direction.  Let's say we evaluate \$i(t)\$ at a particular time and get a positive result.  This arrow just says that positive results mean clockwise current flow.  If we get a negative result at a particular time, then current is flowing opposite the arrow, or counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

Is a negative amplitude eqivalent to a phase oft 180deg?

I don`t think so. To speak about "phase shift", I think, we need to compare two different continuos waveforms - and this is not the case in the example under discussion. If we add a certain positive dc voltage two the symmetrical sinusoidal signal (symmetrical to 0 Volts) the phase of the signal is not touched at all - and the negative half waves are shifted to positive values.

And - yes - in case of positive and negative half waves the direction of the current changes periodically. Why should this be a problem? The formulation "to complete the path" is relevant for dc currents only. What matters is simply the fact if the circuit allows a movement of charges. And this is ensured also in case of an ac signal.

Answer (score 0):

Negative value of current, whether it is alternating or direct, means that the actual current flow is in the opposite to the direction marked.

Negative voltage means that the node marked '+' is actually at a lower potential than the node marked '-'.

Consider the figure:

[image]

The value of V is negative if top node in the figure is at a lower potential when compared with the bottom terminal. *(V is measured by connecting the red probe (+ve) of voltmeter to the top node.)*

The assumed direction of I is in clock wise. The value of I is negative if the actual current flow is in anti-clock wise.

In the negative half cycle of an alternating source, the voltage at +ve terminal will be less than that at -ve terminal and current will flow from the -ve terminal to +ve terminal through the circuit connected to it.

The sign actually depends on how you measure it. You measure the value of a 5V DC voltage source by connecting red probe of multimeter to + terminal and black probe to the - terminal multimeter will show 5V. Instead if you exchange the connection and measure it again, it will show -5V. *(If you are planning to test this, use a multimeter or a voltmeter that can show a -ve reading)*